# PostgreSQL - one big table or thousands small ones?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, database-design

I'm making a service which allows its user to define own tables (columns in them) and save data (rows) to them. Something like spreadsheet or Airtable.com.

I'm wondering what could be the best architecture for saving these data, so that it easily supports selects, joins between these tables and some fulltext search as well. I've come up with these two solutions, can you write me some pros and cons? Thank you.

1) There is a table with list of sheets (tables) and its schema (as JSON). And the second table with raw data. This table has three columns - id, id_sheet (foreign key to sheets) and data (raw in JSONB). It's easy and quite well suited for selects because of JSONB. But the table data might get really big with many users and many tables, and it would be optimized much because of the JSONB.

2) There is a table with list of sheets (tables) and its schema (as JSON). Then, each of these sheets is represented as a new table in database, with columns based on its schema. It would be good, but I'm not sure if it's ok to have too many small tables created by the app.

I know that it's generally a bad idea to let the app create tables in the database, but it could seriously make my website faster and easier to develop. Easier search, selects, joins...

I expect having thousands of users, each having 10-20 sheets ("tables") with hundreds of rows in them. Then, there can be some minority of users with even millions rows, and it could slow down others as well. With each table really defined as Postgre table, it wouldn't be an issue. What do you think?

Comment: I don't even have to read the question.  The answer is "one table" unless you have a really, really compelling reason for proliferation of tables -- like a judge in a lawsuit told you so.  With proper use of indexing and table partitioning, performance shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: I think one table as well.  However, it seems like a NoSQL type database might suit your needs better.

Comment: The idea of creating and altering tables on user whims sounds like a recipe for disaster. "Thousands of users" isn't very big. Keep it simple, use JSONB, it's surprisingly performant. Use it until it causes a performance problem. By that time you'll have more data about how the database is actually reacting and what features the users are actually using.

Comment: One table would also come to my mind as the first. I was just afraid of the case when I'll need some joins, fulltext search, and the one big table will have 100 millions rows and the queries will not be much optimized, because of the unstructured JSONB data.

Comment: Are you sure PostgreSQL is really the best tool for this job?

Comment: I'm not sure if postgresql is the best, but there will be other tables in db which are relational, and i believe that because of the JSONB type, it has what I need, otherwise I'd go for some NoSQL like Mongo.

Comment: The reason I'm not so sure is this article: https://blog.heapanalytics.com/when-to-avoid-jsonb-in-a-postgresql-schema/